# More advanced mathematics with Scala's Numeric and Fractional numbers

Tags: scala, math, exponent

Recently I've (finally) started using Scala's Numeric trait, which does wonders. For example:

```
def square[A](x: A)(implicit num: Numeric[A]): A = num.times(x, x)
```

Now I can square any number be it `Double`, `Integer`, `BigDecimal`, or what not. Yet what if I want to do some more advanced math? For example, my [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for `Double` numbers looks like this:

```
def logisticFunction(x: Double): Double = 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-x))
```

I could do the adding and dividing easily (I'd just have to use trait `Fractional` instead of `Numeric`), but what about the exponent? I sure don't want to write my own `exp` function (or any arbitrary function which takes `Double` arguments).

So, my question is this: how do I convert my `A` to `Double`, do my maths on that, and then convert back to `A`. Is it even possible?

**EDIT:**

That's how the signature of my function should look like:

```
def logisticFunction[A](x: A)(implicit num: Fractional[A]): A = 
  /* Magic happens here */
```

I've figured out the part about converting to double, which is as easy as `num.toDouble(x)`. However the problem of converting back to `A` remains.

Comment: The logisticFunction is never going to return a valid member of A for, for example, Integer, so no, I don't see how it is possible unless you want to start using it as a partially applied function and modify it to match against valid numeric types for the function.

Comment: `import Numeric.Implicits._` and write `x * x` instead of `num.times(x, x)`.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but I'm assuming there are more complicated applications at work here? Why would you write these functions using numeric given how simple they are? I say this because honestly you want to avoid most of the fancy features of Scala for everyday use, trust me on this alot of the features like implicits have no place in robust financial systems.

Comment: @RichardTodd I'm not sure "trust me on this" has much place on a Q&A website, especially when people don't know who you are. How hard is it to provide a justification for your position?

Comment: Shadowlands, I'd use Fraction[A], not Numeric[A] for my logisticFunction. The function doesn't make any sense with integers anyway.
Jean-Philippe Pellet, I tried that but the compiler gave me some hairy errors ("error: type mismatch; [...] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous")
Richard Todd, yes, those are just minimal examples, not my actual code. And if I'd wanted to avoid Scala's features, I'd just stay with Java :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I still doubt this approach is really useful. But with your description, you will want something like this:

```
type FromDouble[A] = Double => A
type ToDouble  [A] = A => Double

def logisticFunction[A: FromDouble: ToDouble](x: A): A = 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-x))

logisticFunction(0.5)
implicit def bigDecimalToDouble(b: BigDecimal) = b.toDouble    
logisticFunction(BigDecimal(0.5))
```

Or with dedicated type class:

```
object FromDouble {
  implicit object _Double extends FromDouble[Double] {
    def apply(d: Double) = d
  }
  implicit object _BigDecimal extends FromDouble[BigDecimal] {
    def apply(d: Double) = BigDecimal(d)
  }
}
trait FromDouble[A] extends (Double => A)

object ToDouble {
  implicit object _Double extends ToDouble[Double] {
    def apply(d: Double) = d
  }
  implicit object _BigDecimal extends ToDouble[BigDecimal] {
    def apply(b: BigDecimal) = b.toDouble
  }
}
trait ToDouble[A] extends (A => Double)

def logisticFunction[A: FromDouble: ToDouble](x: A): A = 1.0 / (1.0 + math.exp(-x))

logisticFunction(0.5)
logisticFunction(BigDecimal(0.5))
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need a type class that provides trigonometric functions such as `exp`. Scala's standard library does not go beyond `Fractional`. You could try to use [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire).

Example:

```
$ sbt core/console

import spire.math._
import spire.algebra._
import spire.implicits._

def logisticFunction[A](x: A)(implicit m: Field[A], t: Trig[A]): A =
  m.one / (m.one + exp(-x))

logisticFunction(0.5)
logisticFunction(BigDecimal(0.5))
```

Comment: My problem is not so much with numbers. I want to create a generic method which accepts any fractional (Double, Float, BigDecimal) number, does math with it and returns the result of the same type. I can do this with simple operations (+, *, etc), but not with arbitrary functions which accept Doubles.

Comment: Then you need type classes for conversions to/from Double, although it seems strange that if you do this math with `Double` you want to convert forth and back in the first place